# problemas con suma php

Tags: php, jquery

en una tabla realizo suma y promedio.

1er- la suma se realiza de todos los campos(mejor dicho, los campos se suman juntos como si fuera todo un solo registro), lo mismo pasa con el promedio que solo me lee la primera linea y obvia las demas.

2do. los datos solo me llegan con un ID aun cuando el ajax me dice que los ID correspondiente fueron enviados.

en la base de datos solo se me registra el id del primer campo y obvia los demas campos

```html
$consulta_tabla_estudiante=mysqli_query($conexion,$profesores);

  while ($registroAsistencia =mysqli_fetch_row($consulta_tabla_estudiante))
  {
$nombre=$registroAsistencia[0];
?>

    
    <td><input type='text' class='notas2 form-control input-sm input' size='1px' name='notas[]' id='p1' onkeyup='sumar();'></td>
     <td><input type='text' class='notas2 form-control input-sm input' size='1' name='notas[]' id='p2'  onkeyup='sumar();'></td>
     <td><input type='text' class='notas2 form-control input-sm input' size='1' name='notas[]' id='p3'  onkeyup='sumar();'></td> 
     <td><input type='text' class='notas2 form-control input-sm input' size='1' name='notas[]' id='p4' onkeyup='sumar();'></td>
     <td><span id='sumaTotal' size='1' class='notas2'><input type='text' id='sumaTotal' name='sumaTotal' size='1' class='form-control input-sm input' readonly=''><span></td>
     <td><span id='promedio'><input type='text' id='promedio' name='promedio' size='1' class='form-control input-sm input' readonly=''><span></td>

     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$nombre; ?>">
```

```html
$fechaNotas=date("Y-m-d h:i a");



if (isset($_POST['notas'])) {//se existe el post de asistencia
 //$nota=array(implode('', $_POST['notas']));
 
foreach ((array) $_POST['notas'] as $notas){
 

 $id=$_POST['id'];

 $sql="INSERT INTO notas(notas,id_estudiante,fecha_notas)
        values ('$notas','$id', '$fechaNotas')";
  echo $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

```html
    //funcion que carcula el promedio de las notas de los estudiantes...
      function porcentaje(){

     var p1=document.getElementById('p1').value;
     var p2=document.getElementById('p2').value;
     var p3=document.getElementById('p3').value;
     var p4=document.getElementById('p4').value;


     var promedio=(parseInt(p1) + parseFloat(p2) + parseFloat(p3) + parseFloat(p4)) /4;
      document.getElementById('promedio').innerHTML = promedio;



      }

  $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#bEnviar').click(function(){
  var datos=$('#formulario').serialize(); //convierte los datos del formulario en cadena.  

alert(datos);
 $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"guardarNotas.php",
   data:datos,
   success:function(r){
     if(r==1) {
      alert ("Notas Reguistradas Exitosamente! :)");
    }else{
      alert ("Fallo La Conexion :(" );
    }
   }
  });
   return false;

  });
});
```

Comment: Vendría muy bien que formatees un poco el código porque es difícil de leer. El problema que veo a simple vista es que el `<input name="id">` al estar dentro de un `while` se repite varias veces con *el mismo nombre*. Por eso se está enviando un solo ID. Deberías transformarlo en un array, como `notas`. `<input name="id[]">`.

Comment: saludos amigo y gracias por responder. me podrias ayudar con la parte que mencionas del id[]. para poder recibirlo solo lo logro anidando el foreach, pero de esa forma cambia el ID a los que quiero y eso esta bien, pero todos los registros toman el mismo ID, luego se repiten todos los registros con el siguiente ID,

Comment: el otro problema es que todo se suma o se le da el promedio solo en la primera fila.